# Heroku Redis Error while reading from socket: (104, 'Connection reset by peer')

Tags: django, heroku, celery

I'm running a Heroku Redis instance that always worked fine, but after the upgrade when I try to run celery workers I get the following error

```
[2021-07-23 11:06:08,135: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to redis://:**@ec2-54-***-***-*.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:*****//: Error while reading from socket: (104, 'Connection reset by peer').
Trying again in 12.00 seconds... (6/100)
```

Everything seems to be up to date and I can't seem to figure out how to run it again. I tried to drop the redis instance and create it from scratch but nothing.

Comment: Did you make sure to connect to the right URI? Apparently the URI is not permanent on Heroku

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am having the same problem. I'm even connecting to os.environ['REDIS_URL'] with the config vars set up in Heroku settings.